# Vanishing Question?

Tags: support, specific-question

A question was posted very recently about monetizing magic in a Renaissance Venice. I commented to suggest some development that might avoid Idea Generation closure. The OP replied with thanks, and I gained a bit of rep. But now the question doesn't exist. My rep history retains it, but the link is dead.

What does this mean?

EDIT: Correction. My history retains that the OP said the comment was helpful, and said thanks, but I did not gain rep from this. It's inbox that retains the entry, not the rep list. Not that it matters -- the answer below is perfectly sufficient -- but I thought it best to clarify for the record.

Comment: It would be quite easy to ask why it was deleted, just give a little ping. @JoelDerfner

Comment: In 215 reputation you'll be able to see the deleted question :) (Until the site graduates and priv requirements all jump up)

Comment: @TimB The site *has* graduated, we're just waiting for the design and rep limits change.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling It's all semantics now. Are we in the process of graduating or have we graduated? I'd argue we haven't until the design and rep changes but instead are in the process of doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The OP deleted [the question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/38457/28).  That's unfortunate, as you left a good comment explaining how he could adjust the question.  He didn't leave any comments explaining the deletion, so unless he comes by again or visits chat or something, we can't know.

I don't see anything related to that question that would have generated reputation for you.  Perhsps you've confused it with a different source of rep?

Comment: I think maybe he or she up-voted my comment. It's 5 points. In any event, I'm glad to hear that was why it's missing -- though I thought it was a potentially interesting question. Oh well.

Comment: Oh -- nope, I misstated. My mistake. My history reflects that the OP said something nice about my reply, that's all. No rep involved. But I now have a history entry that has no question linked to it, because the question is missing. Whatever.

Comment: @CAgrippa Right. Back when I was still new around these parts, I even suggested that [comment upvotes should earn a small amount of reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/82685/157730). It didn't really go anywhere, and was closed as a duplicate of a [much earlier question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296/157730)...